# Abstract class Container - Python

Tags: python, oop, abstract-class, duck-typing, built-in-types

I am trying to understand why any class that has the `__contains__` method becomes an instance of the Container abstract class. I am getting a little confused because the correct way should be like this `class dumb(Container):` and define your own `__contains__` method.

It supposes to be because of **duck typing** but where is the duck typing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are able to customize `isinstance` checks by implementing `__subclasshook__`.
Many classes will choose to look at properties of the instance to determine the type rather than relying on the inheritance hierarchies

For example, [this is how Container is implemented](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3875a6954741065b136650db67ac533bc70a3eac/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L388-L402)

> ````
> class Container(metaclass=ABCMeta):
>
>     __slots__ = ()
>
>     @abstractmethod
>     def __contains__(self, x):
>         return False
>
>     @classmethod
>     def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
>         if cls is Container:
>             return _check_methods(C, "__contains__")
>         return NotImplemented
>
>     __class_getitem__ = classmethod(GenericAlias) ```
> ````

Comment: So the duck typing is on the new class having the ´__contains__´ method. I mean, it has the method so it must be a Container. Thanks for the answer, helped me a lot to fully understand.

Answer (score 1):

*If it walks like a duck and it quacks like a duck, then it must be a duck.*

Duck typing is the idea that, in some cases, an object can be defined moreso by its functionality than by its class designation. By including a `__contains__` method, the implication is that the object functions as a container.